# what's the difference between `kill %1` and `kill $pid`?

Tags: shell, process, jobs, kill

Recently, I'm working on an script which used to launch job from file, assume the following job:

```
while true; do nc -l 8188 < index.html; done &
```

when I run it in an interactive shell, and I got an pid echo back like this:

```
[1] 31095
```

the `pstree(1)` output:

bash(31095, 31095) ---- nc(31096,31095)

both the `while` clause and the `nc(1)` command are in the same process group.

1. When I type `kill 30995`, the `while` clause terminated as expected, but the `nc(1)` was left. I guess that kill statement just invoke the `kill(2)` system call.
2. When I type `kill %1`, the entire 31095 process group was killed. I thing that may invoke `killpg(2)` internally.
3. When I type 'fg' to bring the background to front, and then type 'Ctrl-C' to send the interrupt signal, then both the `while` clause and the `nc(1)` command gone, I think that's because the `INT` signal was sent to the process group as described in item 2.

I also download the bash-4.3-beta source code, but the source code is too much and I cannot find the related stuff. Could someone help me make my thoughts clear?

But when I put the above background job in script, `kill %1` doesn't work as I guessed any more. Here is the script(kill2.sh):

```
while true; do
    nc -l 8888 < $0
done &

trap 'kill %1' INT TERM
wait || wait
```

I run this by `bash kill2.sh`, and then the `pstree -pg 31835` result:

```
bash(31835, 31835) -- bash(31836, 31835) -- nc(31837, 31835)
```

when I type `ctrl-c`, 31835 and 31836 was killed, but nc was left. So I'm wondering if there's a special case for `kill %1` in the script context?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. When I type `kill 30995`, the `while`
>      clause terminated as expected, but the `nc(1)` was left. I
>      guess that kill statement just invoke the `kill(2)` system
>      call.
> 2. When I type `kill %1`, the entire 31095
>      process group was killed. I thing that may invoke
>      `killpg(2)` internally.
> 3. When I type 'fg' to bring
>      the background to front, and then type 'Ctrl-C' to send the interrupt
>      signal, then both the `while` clause and the
>      `nc(1)` command gone, I think that's because the
>      `INT` signal was sent to the process group as described in
>      item 2.

1. That's true.
2. It might invoke `killpg()`, but at least on Linux, `killpg()` is implemented as a library function that makes the call `kill(-pgrp, sig)`.
3. True, if the terminal is the controlling terminal of a foreground process group, the Interrupt character will cause a SIGINT to be sent to this group.

> But when I put the above background job in script, `kill %1` doesn't work as I guessed any more. … So I'm wondering if
>   there's a special case for `kill %1` in the script context?

The *jobspec* `%1` is only usable when job control is enabled. Job control is disabled by default for non-interactive shells. You can enable job control in the script by inserting the command `set -m`.